# How to change the name of "Modifier" field in edit configuration of jira gadget- I want to change "Modifier" to "Edit Title "

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

How to change the name of "Modifier" field in edit configuration of jira gadget- I want to change "Modifier" to "Edit Title "

- List item

  [image: I want to change Modifier to Edit Title I have provided with the screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably defined in

atlassian-gadgets-dashboard/plugin/src/main/resources/com/atlassian/gadgets/dashboard/internal/i18n_fr.properties

which would require rebuilding the plugin that provides standard gadgets for JIRA. Not an easy thing but possible.

Comment: Hi , Thanks a lot for you reply . I did as you said and made necessary changes in the "i18n_fr.properties" file using JAVA       De - compiler . I ran the command atlas-mvn eclipse:eclipse and then run the project but the changes are not visible . I think as you suggested I will have to rebuild the whole plugin . My main task is to change the title of the plugin according to the user input .

Comment: I Have made a customized user preference for that as u can see in the above image  "Edit Content" . In this I have made a text field to enter the title the user wants but on clicking update it does not reflect the changes . The changes are only reflected when I refresh or reload the page .

Comment: Is there a way with which I could reload the page or update the changes as soon as the button is clicked . I tried using reloading script but it is not on the button click . It keeps reloading infinite times after the page is loaded first time . Thank you so much for your patients . I really appreciate your answer and would be really grateful of you if you could provide me with a solution . Thank you so much